# how to see the prototype body in console javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function Person() {
    this.firstName;
    this.lastName;
    this.age;
    this.eyeColor;
    this.nationality;
}
var luffy = new Person();
luffy.firstName="Monkey";
console.log(luffy);
```

In this if i open in console it'll show an firstName,but i where can i see the body of this object,i mean where can i see whats there in this object prototype...as we can see the constructor if we open object proto,same way i want to see the body of this objects parent...please help me out(i haven't given anything as an argument in the prototype,i.e, person)

Comment: If you expand the object, it should show a `__proto__` property. That’s the prototype. Also note that all the `this.firstName; this.lastName; …` statements do absolutely nothing.

Comment: All of those statements in your constructor evaluate to `undefined` and have no side-effects. They don't modify the object or its prototype in any way.

Comment: `luffy.constructor`?

Comment: @BrettDeWoodyny You are spot on! :-)

Comment: There is nothing in your objects prototype but the `.constructor`. That's expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `> luffy.constructor` which will return the constructor definition.

use `> luffy.__proto__` to know about the prototype of the object.

```js
function Person() {
    this.firstName;
    this.lastName;
    this.age;
    this.eyeColor;
    this.nationality;
}
var luffy = new Person();
luffy.firstName="Monkey";

console.log(luffy.constructor);  // returns the constructor i.e., is the definition of the function contructor
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) to return the constructor function that created the instance object.

In your case:

```
> luffy.contructor

< function Person() {
    this.firstName;
    this.lastName;
    this.age;
    this.eyeColor;
    this.nationality;
  }
```